# Какие есть способы создания кнопки и написания ее функции?

Tags: swift, xcode, uibutton

Если есть возможность, то напишите код для кнопки, которая изменяла бы свое название при нажатии

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("gwg")
}
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
}
}
```

пишу на iOS. Swift 5, Xcode 11.

Comment: Не нужно писать в заголовке свою биографию

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создадим переменную `@State var buttonName = "gwg"`

Потом саму кнопку (в теле body) `Button(buttonName){ buttonName = "newName" }`

Как-то так. Надеюсь помог!

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Отметьте пожалуйста как верный ответ (На галочку нажать)